# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Form OnFailure never called!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

The Ajax request is as follows:

In the controller action method I tried to add ModelState Error as well as throw an exception but response is never calling OnFailure. It always calls the OnSuccess regardless of response. May be I missing somthing here.

The question: When is it going to call the OnFailure js method? Any samples will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to return an HTTP error status code from your action.  E.g. 400, 404, 500.

try something like this:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not Found");
```

Comment: The answer listed above should work. You can check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37332246/4896260) which gives a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MSDN definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure(v=vs.118).aspx), OnFailure is called when the HTTP response status is not in the 200 range. For instance if its a permanent Redirect (308), temporary redirect (307) Not Found (404) or Bad Request (400) then the OnFailure method is called. For a full list of HTTP response codes, [see this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)