# Razor MVC 5.2.3 how to call OnFailure with ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ajax form in which I would like to call two different javascript functions, one for success and one for failure. In both of these calls, I [pass data back from the server to the javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978082/4896260). Please note the following:

I have this in my view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST", // HttpPost
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "myDiv", 
    OnSuccess = "callSuccess(data.msg)",
    OnFailure = "callFailure(data.msg)",
}, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
   ... // my content
}
```

My controller has the following logic when return the post.

```
    public ActionResult MyAction(string myString)
    {
        ...
        // If error occurred
        return Json(new { success = false, msg= "Fail" });
        ...
        // If no errors
        return Json(new { success = true, msg= "Success" });
    }
```

No matter what is returned, `OnSuccess` is the only one that gets called. What is the proper way to call `OnFailure`?

Comment: Your returning valid data (not throwing an exception or returning an error code) so it will always go to the success function.

Comment: "success" means that the ajax call was successful - ie the http request/receive process completed without an http error.  AJAX doesn't know that you have a "success" property set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from Rion Williams post, I was able to call both functions. More importantly, I figured out how to access and display the desired message upon success/failure:

My controller

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string myString)
{
    ...
    // If error occurred
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error occurred!");
    ...
    // If no errors
    return Json(new { success = true, msg= "Success" });
}
```

My view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST", // HttpPost
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "myDiv", 
    OnSuccess = "callSuccess(data.msg)",
    OnFailure = "callFailure(error)",    // error = "Error occurred!"
}, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
   ... // my content
}
```

Comment: This will no longer work with HTTP/2 as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922043/custom-error-message-with-httpstatuscoderesult-not-working-on-localhost

Comment: This also depends on what went wrong in the "if error" part.  Was it really a bad request? Or did something else go wrong (eg disk full would not be a "bad request").  Use the correct HttpStatusCode.

Answer (score 2):

**Consider Using HTTP Status Codes**

You could consider returning the appropriate [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) that corresponds with the type of error you want to trigger (i.e. Unauthorized, Bad Request, etc.) by returning an [`HttpStatusCodeResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) object :

```
// If an error occurred...
if(error)
{
     // Indicate your code and error message. This uses the Bad Request status (400) 
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Something went wrong...");
}
```

**Handling This Client-Side**

If you didn't want to do this, you could consider defining a single result event (i.e. `OnSuccess = "call(data);`) and then within that event, check your `success` property to determine what to do :

```
function call(data){
      if(data.success){
          callSuccess(data.msg);
      }
      else{
          callFailure(data.msg);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will always call OnSuccess.
But you can check your success Property inside onSuccess function.

```
    OnSuccess : function (data)
 {                     
    if(success)
    {
    alert('Json Return Success')
    }
    else
    {
    alert('json Result False')
    }

}
```

Otherwise you have to send error status as Rion Williams mention

Comment: If that's the case, is there a purpose for the `OnFailure` Ajax option? Or is it triggered by returning a `HttpStatusCodeResult` ?

Comment: If any error comes up during run time then instead of onSuccess it goes to OnFailure. You can also add error like this as well..   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Enter all the values");.  I hope it goes to onFailure